# Python SAML Authentication Automation

Tags: python, saml

I am trying to work on a project that collects all my monthly utility amounts and disperses the amounts owed to my roommates. I have managed to programmatically log into two websites but I am having trouble with the last, as they are using SAML (https://www.blackhillsenergy.com/). I have inspected the web requests with Chrome's Developer Tools but I am not getting any breakthroughs. I attempted to use requests_ecp but I am not having any luck with that either. I get the idea of SAML but having a hard time understanding their implementation and how I can use it in my script. Below is my sample code? Any ideas?

```
def get_bh_bill():

    url = 'https://www.blackhillsenergy.com/cpm/v1/user/accounts?username={fill here}'
    bh_login = ''
    bh_pass = ‘'

    # Start a session so we can have persistent cookies
    session = requests.session()

    session.auth = HTTPECPAuth('https://sso.blackhillsenergy.com', username=bh_login, password=bh_pass)
    acc_res = session.get(url)
    acc_soup = BeautifulSoup(acc_res.text, "html.parser")


    print(acc_soup.prettify())

    return '0000'
```

Answer (score 3):

SAML, typically, works like this.

You hit the desired site, they see you are not authenticated, so they create a SAML request, route it through your browser, and send you to an IdP, Identity Provider.

The IdP reads the SAML request, and then asks you for credentials. Once authenticated, it creates a SAML response, and routes that back to the original site, through your browser.

The routing is done by presenting a simple HTML form containing the SAML Request/Response, and a teeny bit of javascript to submit it. This is how it moves information across domains (SAML is typically done across domains, this is why it doesn't use cookies.)

What your script needs to do is basically follow the workflow, submit the forms automatically, login when asked, and submit the forms back. It's a multi step workflow. There may well be a bunch of redirects involved as well.

[image]